# pandas epoch time conversion `ms` to `s`

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with an epoch time stamp in `ms`. I wish to convert to `s` and I have simply been dividing by 1000.0. However, this returns this following.

```
df['time_stamp'] = df['time_ms'] / 1000.0

print df.head()

 time_ms       time_stamp 
 1486339200000     1.486339e+09
```

Why is this converting the type? Using `1000.0` and not `1000` should keep the correct format. When I subsequently try and find the day or date using `dt.day` from this, it fails.

Desired output

```
     time_ms       time_stamp 
     1486339200000       1486339200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is you divide by `float`, output `dtype` is `float` too.

```
df['time_stamp'] = (df['time_ms'] / 1000.0)
print (df)
         time_ms    time_stamp
0  1486339200000  1.486339e+09

print (df.dtypes)
time_ms         int64
time_stamp    float64
dtype: object
```

So then works cast to `int`:

```
df['time_stamp'] = (df['time_ms'] / 1000.0).astype(np.int64)
print (df)
         time_ms  time_stamp
0  1486339200000  1486339200
```